# Calculating cube root of 4012 by long division method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: y]

Find cube root of 4012.

So this is what I've done so far. The problem is 3012 divided by 300 is 10 something. I don't think I can put a quotient of two figures on top. I'm stuck please help thanks.

Comment: Note:  $\sqrt[3]{4096}=16$

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52605.html